# how to get the contents of an iframe that is dynamically placed

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamic

I have a program (called 'PersonalBrain') that exports to html using very complicated javascript (based on Prototype). The script places an iframe inside a div in a main html file. The result is that a searchengine cannot index the content of the iframe. Changing the script is not an option. My idea is now to somehow get the content of the iframe and place this inside another div in the main html - in such a way that this is indexable (and then hide it with css). How would I do that? It needs to be in plain javascript (or maybe php?). 
BTW: the id of the iframe is also placed dynamically.
A live example can be found on https://www.wideopenwindows.be

Comment: I have already noticed that the following code works offline, but not online:

`var c = $('body').html();
$('#framecontent', window.parent.document).html(c);`

It gives an error:
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

and freezes the browser window :-(

Comment: btw, i used this code inside the the code of the iframe

Comment: 'var c = $('body').text(); $('#framecontent', window.parent.document).text(c);'

this does work!
I am very curious if google can index this...